# Identify the plane defined by $\arg{(i^2\cdot\overline{z})}=\pi$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I tried:

$$\arg{(i^2\cdot\overline{z})}=\pi \Leftrightarrow \\
\arg{(-1)}+\arg{(\overline{z})} = \pi \Leftrightarrow \\
\pi + \arg(\overline{z}) = \pi \Leftrightarrow \\
\arg(\overline{z}) = 0 \Leftrightarrow \\
???$$

What do I do next?

Comment: $\arg (\bar z)=-\arg(z)=0\implies \theta=2n\pi $

Comment: @Dr.MV Nice, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome Mark.  -Mark

Comment: Note that this defines a line, not a plane.